# Частота запросов к api карт и геокодеру

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть задача спарсить координаты нескольких тысяч населенных пунктов и расстояния до них от МКАД. Программная часть у меня готова, оттестирована и прекрасно работает. Есть вопрос: С какой частотой можно отправлять запросы к api карт и геокодеру, чтобы не попасть под санкции? В текущем виде парсер отправляет 10-12 запросов в минуту - это нормально?

Answer (score 0):

Использовать API Яндекс.Карт для парсинга данных запрещено пользовательским соглашением. Такой сервис может быть заблокирован автоматически.

Для легитимного использования с показом карты и без сохранения данных лимит ограничен только в сутки - 25 000 запросов в бесплатной версии.

Comment: Карта показывается, маршрут отображается на карте, измеренное расстояние и полученные координаты отображаются на странице в html элементах. Сам скрипт, равно как и страница, ничего не сохраняет. Это легально? По факту, конечно,  сохранение данных есть, но не браузерными средствами.

Comment: запрещено сохранять данные, полученные от API. Если, допустим, вы строите маршрут, а потом сохраняете его километраж и время в пути к себе для будущего использования, то это запрещено. Аналогично, если человек кликнул по карте, а вы сохранили адрес (дом, улица) этой точки к себе в базу

Comment: Спасибо, Reni, я уже почитал соглашение. Всвязи с этим возник ещё один вопрос. Ведь никто не запрещает использовать для построения маршрута координаты, полученные из публичного сервиса yandex.ru/maps/ ? Простите, что все расспрашиваю, я ведь не программист, а водитель, и последний раз что-то писал в рамках школьной программы, 22 года назад..

Comment: И ещё, можно на карте отобразить не весь маршрут, а его часть от определенной точки до конечной?

Comment: Строить маршрут по координатам можно, отображать только часть маршрута также.

Comment: Всё, сдаюсь. Как можно отобразить часть маршрута? Например: есть маршрут состоящий из N сегментов. Как можно не отображать первые 7 сегментов? Цифра 7, понятно, условная... При построении маршрута используется ymaps.route() Или где об этом почитать? (Пример кода, правда, меня обрадует больше ))) )

Comment: лучше задайте отдельный вопрос, приложив свой код, с которым возникли трудности